# Can you create a primary xml index in the CREATE TABLE statement (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2017, xml, snapshot-isolation

I'm creating a temporary table and would like to create a primary and secondary XML index on a contained xml column within the `CREATE TABLE` statement since that is the only way I can create an index without throwing an error under snapshot isolation.

I know the syntax for creating standard (non-XML) clustered and nonclustered indexes inline, and it works fine, but I don't seem to be able to find a syntax that works for XML indexes either in documentation or via experimentation.

Does anyone know whether this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried using the XML index creation commands in-lined with a table creation, and it didn't work.

I stumbled upon this [article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/getting-started-with-xml-indexes/) that makes it look like trying to create non-relational indexes (XML, columnstore, or spatial) doesn't work with in-lining the index creation statement in the table definition.

Comment: Disappointing, but I'll just need to find another way.  Thanks!